# Event handling in tableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, uievent

What I'm trying to do is handling touch events so that when i screen is getting touched, i want to take some action. For example changing background color
The things i tried: // I subclassed table view controller

```
override func touchesEnded(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
     tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.orangeColor()
}
```

that didn't work, i suspected that tvc may not be first responder so that table view handles the touch events. So i tried:

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()
     tableView.resignFirstResponder()    
}
```

Also tried:

```
override func becomeFirstResponder() -> Bool {
    return true
}

override func canBecomeFirstResponder() -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

None of them work. How can i handle events ? What I'm missing?

**EDIT**

***The selected answer in terms of native swift code:***

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        var tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "tap:")
        tapGestureRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = true
        self.tableView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)




    }

    func tap(recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        if recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Ended {
            var tapLocation  = recognizer.locationInView(self.tableView)
            var tapIndexPath : NSIndexPath? = self.tableView.indexPathForRowAtPoint(tapLocation)

            if let index = tapIndexPath  {

                self.tableView(self.tableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath: index)
            } else {
                self.tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.orangeColor()
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Do you want something to happen when you select a cell, or just when you press on the screen?

Comment: Actually, the main plan is to create new cell, when get touched. For learning purposes I'm experimenting with other properties. So i tried to change tableView's background color here. But couldn't do

Comment: Why u are trying to detect touch in TableView, as there are cell inside it, which will receive the touch.

Comment: As i mentioned in my previous comment, main thing is to create a new cell when tableView get touched. Consider tableView dataArray = ["1","2"]. These will be printed on screen right? But screen will be filled with some additional cells, which will not receive didSelectRowAtIndexPath message. So i need some other way to take some action when these additional cells are getting touched.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to react to touches all over the view, not just the cells, add a tap gesture recognizer in viewDidLoad:

```
- (void)addTapGestureForListTable {
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(userTappedOnView:)];
    tapGestureRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = YES;
    [self.tableView addGestureRecognizer:tapGestureRecognizer];
}
```

And then implement the method userTappedOnView. If you want to distinguish between touches on cells or not, implement it like so:

```
- (void)userTappedOnView:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
    if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
        CGPoint tapLocation = [recognizer locationInView:self.tableView];
        NSIndexPath *tapIndexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:tapLocation];
        if (tapIndexPath) {
            [self tableView:self.tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:tapIndexPath];
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to react to touches on a cell, you have to make your tableView's delegate point to the controller. In viewDidLoad do:

```
self.tableView.delegate = self;
```

And then implement the method

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

Comment: Awesome. Very good answer in terms of obj-c. I tried last 40 min to translate that in to Swift native code. Anyway, i got it working now.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, not sure if this is what you are looking for but I think you would still be better off handling the tableView actions though the built in methods. Use custom UITableViewCells and determine what to do depending on the subclass of the cell.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    var selectedCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)

    if let addTableViewCell = selectedCell as? AddNewTableViewCell {
        insertNewObject(addTableViewCell)
    } else if let someOtherTableViewCell = selectedCell as? SomeOtherTableViewCell {
        // Do something else
    }
}

// Copied from the Xcode template
func insertNewObject(sender: AnyObject) {
    objects.insert(NSDate(), atIndex: 0)
    let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0)
    self.tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
}
```

Comment: Hello. main plan is to create a new cell when tableView get touched. Consider tableView dataArray = ["1","2"]. These will be printed on screen right? But screen will be filled with some additional cells, which will not receive didSelectRowAtIndexPath message. So i need some other way to take some action when these additional cells are getting touched.